# ionic 2: http get request not working (proxy added)

Tags: httprequest, ionic2

I'm using Http from @angular/http to send GET requests, but the server is not receiving the request. The generated urls are correct because when I log them and open them in browser (I've tried all of Chrome, Firefox and Safari), the server does receive these requests.

This is how I am doing this:

```
let logButtonUrl = this.urlGenerator.generateTiramisuUrlTemp(this.servletPath, 
  argMap);

console.log("logButtonUrl:"+logButtonUrl);
return this.http.get(logButtonUrl).map(this.writeSuccess);
```

Function writeSuccess:

```
private writeSuccess(res: Response) {
   let body = res.json();
   let rows_affected = body.data[0].rowsAffected;
   if (rows_affected == "1") {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
```

}

I got no error message in browser console, so it's probably not because of the CORS issue discussed here: 
http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

I also tried using a proxy. I added this in ionic.config.json:

```
{
"path": "/backendTemp",
proxyUrl": "http://128.237.217.70:8080" /*the ip address of the target server*/
}
```

And replace the ip address in my generated urls with "/backendTemp". Still not working.

Any suggestions/thoughts on this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the $http (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
.controller('RequestCtrl', function ($http) {

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://128.237.217.70:8080/backendTemp'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is this for ionic2 or ionic1?

Comment: @TeddyDing It is for either, as it is not ionic specific. $http is an Angular function.

Comment: Thanks! I later discovered that I simply had to handle the promise that http.get returns. Silly error....